# how to use sumOf in cakephp by multiplying two column in cake php

Tags: cakephp-3.0

**I have a table that is look like below**

[image]

**I want to use sumOf on query by multiplying quantity and sub_total column**
*how to i solve this please help me*

*i am getting only sum of sub total by this*

```
   $totalAmount = $this->OrderItems->find()->hydrate(false)->sumOf('sub_total'‌​);
```

*but i would like to multiply quantity and sub_total to making a virtual field for sumOf()*

Answer (score 1):

There are several way. You can do it by creating a virtual field
Add those line in your model `entity`

```
// src/Model/Entity/OrderItems.php
protected $_virtual = ['gtotal'];

    protected function _getGtotal(){
        return $this->_properties['quantity'] * $this->_properties['sub_total'];
    }
```

then you can call it from anywhere by using `gtotal` field
like

```
$totalAmount = $this->OrderItems->find()

foreach ($totalAmount as $key => $amount) {
    echo $amount->gtotal;
}
```

For more check [Creating Virtual Properties](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/entities.html#creating-virtual-properties)

Comment: i am getting only sum of sub total by this ***$totalAmount = $this->OrderItems->find()->hydrate(false)->sumOf('sub_total');***

Comment: if you add above line in your `entity` no need to use `someOf`, you will get a filed name 'gtotal' in your data array

Comment: but i would like to multiply quantity and sub_total to making a virtual field for sumOf()

Comment: then try **`$this->OrderItems->find()->hydrate(false)->sumOf('gtotal'‌​);`**

Comment: I am getting ***Error: syntax error, unexpected '‌​' (T_STRING) ***